# Prove that the interchange of derivatives with infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n$ and $f_n'$ are continuous on $(a, b)$, and the series
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)
$$
converges pointwise, and the series
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(x)
$$
converges uniformly, then $f$ is differentiable and $f' = g$.
I know that this result holds for successions of functions, so let's do a similar test to see if it works.

Let $x\in (a, b)$ s.t.

\begin{align}
    \int_{a}^{x} \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(t) \, dt &=\int_{a}^{x} \left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n f_k'(t) \right) \, dt \\
     &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\int_{a}^{x}\sum_{k=1}^n f_k'(t) \, dt \right) \hspace{0.5cm} \text{conv unif. allows exchange}  \\
     &=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{a}^{x}f_k'(t)  \, dt  \\
     &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(a) \hspace{0.5cm} \text{evaluating the int.}
\end{align}

So $$\int_{a}^{x} \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n'(t) \, dt+\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n}(x)$$

And using T.F.C for the continuity of $f'_{n}$ should conclude the result, what do you think? any comments or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the domain is given as $(a,b)$, $f(a), f_n(a)$ do not even make sense. You can carry out the same argument with integrals from $c$ to $x$ instead of integrals from $a$ to $x$, where $c$ is a fixed point of $(a,b)$. [Recall that $\int_c^{x}=-\int_x^{c}$ if $c >x$].

At the end you need continuity of $\sum f_n'$ and this follows by continuity of each $f_n'$ and uniform convergence.